# how do I 'fix' jquery lightbox so that it doesn't scroll?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, blogger

I added a lightbox to my blogger blog: BibleProphecyBlog.com, using code from here:

http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2011/09/add-one-time-email-subscription-pop-up.html

How do I prevent the lightbox from scrolling. I want it to stay in place when scrolling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `#popupContact` rule on your page (line 451) to have a `position:fixed !important` value.  See below.

```
#popupContact
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed !important; /* changed this part */
    _position: absolute;
    height: 384px;
    width: 408px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #CECECE;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```